# Checkbox from ajax doesn't appear in angular scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this structure

```
<tr ng-repeat="load in loads">
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" ng-model="selected[load.id]" /></td>
</tr>
```

that comes from an AJAX request. If I click the checkbox and press the submit button I don't see the "selected" model into $scope. I've created a static checkbox outside the loop and that one is in scope. Is there something that I'm missing with AJAX content?

Comment: What does $scope.selected do?

Comment: Well, if I log $scope.selected I get "undefined"...

Comment: Try initializing `selected` when controller loads. `$scope.selected=[]`
Then try again.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've said in your comment your `$scope.selected` is `undefined` try to initialize it.

Add to this to your contoller

```
$scope.selected = {};
```

Take a look at this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZoL9O1OykBNnUi77ZhX5?p=preview), this should solve your problem, if I understood it correctly

Comment: Thanks for your reply, in my case I'll have to user Raghu's comment, but your solution also works ;)